# HttpSendRequest failed, Error: The operation timed out (0x80072ee2)

Tags: roblox

**This is a ROBLOX question.** I have a problem with ROBLOX when when I try to play a game after some time it says **HttpSendRequest failed, Error: The operation timed out 0x80072ee2.** (And some link that probably isn't necessary) I have searched a lot of solutions like Restarting the computer or re-installing ROBLOX but only sometimes it works. ( Then it cant work at all after for some reason) If you have any solutions or answers to why I'm having that error or how to fix that please tell me! Again this is a **ROBLOX** question. I have a **Lenovo IdeaPad S145 14-WL.**

Comment: so for some time it works? do you know [there is a upper limits for requests](https://www.swipetips.com/how-to-turn-on-http-requests-in-roblox/)? "Please note that each server has a limit of 500 HTTP requests per minute. In case you exceeded the limit, the service holds off for 30 seconds or so."

Comment: Is this when you are playing your own game, or someone else's?

Comment: Also I forgot to mention this but when I visit my grandmas house ROBLOX works there??? It is like when I change my internet it works...

Comment: @eis I'm trying to open Roblox Studio but it wont work, How can I fix this?

Comment: if it works in one place but not at other then it seems there is something wrong with your internet connectivity. based on this information we can't really know what is wrong with it though.

Comment: What do you mean by that and what do i have to do?? @eis

Comment: @Eggman I mean the problem seems to be not related to roblox but your internet, so we can't help.